# HTML capabilities on eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse

I am learning html on eclipse. It works, I already posted something on a web service. But I cannot use the html capabilities (see the colors that make life easier when programming), it just looks like a .txt file

[image]

Any ideas of how to make this .txt code to look like a html code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the file's `Open With` context menu to actually open it in the HTML Editor. Eclipse will reopen the last editor you used for a given file by default.